# Mandar una variable en el asunto de PHP MAILER

Tags: php, html, mysql

Tengo un formulario el cual al terminarlo se envían los datos a un correo, ya envía los datos, solo quiero que en el asunto se envíe desde donde se envía la información, tengo el siguiente código:

```
$nombre = utf8_decode($_POST['nombre']);

$plantel = utf8_decode($_POST['plantel']);

$carrera = utf8_decode($_POST['carrera']);

$telefono = utf8_decode($_POST['telefono']);

$sugerencia = utf8_decode($_POST['sugerencia']);

___________________
include 'PHPMailer/class.smtp.php';

require 'PHPMailer/class.phpmailer.php';

______
///Envio de correo///
$mail = new PHPMailer();

$mail->IsSMTP();

$mail->Host = "......"; // SMTP a utilizar. 

$mail->Port = 25; // Puerto a utilizar

$mail->SMTPAuth = true;

$mail->Username = "....."; // Correo completo a utilizar

$mail->Password = "....."; // Contraseña

$mail->From = "......."; // Desde donde enviamos (Para mostrar)

$mail->FromName = "BUZON";

$mail->AddAddress ="......."; // Esta es la dirección a donde enviamos

$mail->IsHTML(true); // El correo se envía como HTML

$mail->AddBCC("....."); // Copia oculta

        $mail->Subject = "ENVIADO DE (Aquí quiero que baya en plantel)"; // Este es el titulo del email.

        $mail->Body    = utf8_decode('
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
      <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
      <head></head>
            <body >

            <table class="container text-center" style="  vertical-align: top; width: 580px;">
                <tbody>
                    <tr class="active">
                        <th style="background-color: #E78715; color: #fff; text-align: left; border: 1px solid; border-color: #E78715;" WIDTH="20" HEIGHT="50">&nbsp;&nbsp;NOMBRE DEL <br>&nbsp;&nbsp;ALUMNO:
                        </th>
                        <td style="background-color: #FAFAFA; color: #000; border: 1px solid; border-color: #E78715;" WIDTH="10" HEIGHT="10">&nbsp;&nbsp;'.$_POST['nombre'].'
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr class="active">
                        <th style="background-color: #E78715; color: #fff; text-align: left; border: 1px solid; border-color: #E78715;" WIDTH="20" HEIGHT="50">&nbsp;&nbsp;PLANTEL:
                        </th>
                        <td style="background-color: #FAFAFA; color: #000; border: 1px solid; border-color: #E78715;">&nbsp;&nbsp;'.$_POST['plantel'].'
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr class="active">
                        <th style="background-color: #E78715; color: #fff; text-align: left; border: 1px solid; border-color: #E78715;" WIDTH="20" HEIGHT="50">&nbsp;&nbsp;CARRERA:
                        </th>
                        <td style="background-color: #FAFAFA; color: #000; border: 1px solid; border-color: #E78715;">&nbsp;&nbsp;'.$_POST['carrera'].'
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr class="active">
                        <th style="background-color: #E78715; color: #fff; text-align: left; border: 1px solid; border-color: #E78715;" WIDTH="20" HEIGHT="50">&nbsp;&nbsp;TELÉFONO:
                        </th>
                        <td style="background-color: #FAFAFA; color: #000; border: 1px solid; border-color: #E78715;">&nbsp;&nbsp;'.$_POST['telefono'].'
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr class="active">
                        <th style="background-color: #E78715; color: #fff; text-align: left; border: 1px solid; border-color: #E78715;" WIDTH="20" HEIGHT="50">&nbsp;&nbsp;QUEJA O SUGERENCIA:
                        </th>
                        <td style="background-color: #FAFAFA; color: #000; border: 1px solid; border-color: #E78715;">&nbsp;&nbsp;'.$_POST['sugerencia'].'
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </table>
   </body>
    </html>');
        $mail->AltBody = 'Ejemplo';

if (!$mail->send()) {

        echo '<script language="javascript">

                alert("Ocurrio un error al envíar los datos");

                window.location.href="index.html";

              </script>';

    }


$obj->registro_buzon( $nombre, $plantel, $carrera, $telefono, $sugerencia )
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Puedes añadir una variable PHP sin problema.

$misubject = "ENVIADO DE ".$plantel;
$mail->Subject = $misubject;

Comment: Muchas muchas gracias, me ayudo a resolver el problema perfectamente... gracias :)

Comment: No hay de que, me alegro que te sirviera